# Exchange 2010 Sp3 Upgrade, WCF/HTTP Activation Missing

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, asp.net

I have a customers Exchange 2010 Sp1 server that needs to be upgraded to Sp3 prior to moving them to Exchange 2013.  I am trying to install Exchange 2010 Sp3 update and get the following error

```
The .NET Framework feature 'HTTP Activation' isn't installed.  User Server Manager to install HTTP Activation.
```

When I add that feature I get the following error.

```
Add-WindowsFeature : Installation of [.NET Framework 3.5.1 Features] HTTP Activation failed. Attempt to install HTTP Activation failed with error code 0x80070643.  Fatal error during installation
```

Through some research I have found that by removing the Windows Process Activation Service feature I will be able to install the WCF and HTTP Activation feature and then re-install the WPA Service.

http://www.techieshelp.com/cannot-install-net-framework-3-5-1-on-server-2008-0x80070643/

My question is:  Will removing the WPA Service from a functioning Exchange 2010 install cause issues with Exchange functionality?  Will I be able to re-install this feature successfully afterwards?  All blogs do not discuss this issue with Exchange 2010 already running on the server, only issues with install...

Comment: I read that sometimes it successfully installs if you disable IPv6. Didn't test this myself, but knowing Windows it could as well be correct. The server has to be online 24x7, I assume?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried disabling IPv6 but it didn't help with the install.  Yes it is a 24x7 environment but only a single server.  Maintenance needs to be scheduled a week in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No technical answer here but our decision was to simply build a new Exchange 2010 box, install Sp3 on it and migrate mailboxes there as a holding server for Exchange 2013.

Comment: I used the same procedure last time I upgraded Exchange. The in-place upgrades are somewhat...difficult, sometimes, most of the time.